# Unable to use icon fonts alongwith AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, icons, icon-fonts

I am using [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) for icon fonts in my AngularJS framework based project. However, I am not able to generate these icons because of the Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE). Instead of showing the icons it is showing the HTML number codes of that icon such as "`&#xe006;`"

Please guide me

Comment: https://github.com/picardy/angular-fontawesome

Comment: I think it was my bad I was trying to bind HTML number codes, which is why this happened. Now, I've started using class names and its working. :) I've not much used icomoon that is why this hasty mistake. Thank you Rachel.

Comment: no problem. glad you got it sorted. font awesome is awesome tho! :)

Comment: @RachelGallen Font Awesome is a set of icons. IcoMoon is a tool for creating icon fonts.

Comment: @zeroflagL well if she couldn't create them its a good alternative!!!

Comment: @RachelGallen You cannot use arbitrary icons as alternative to custom-made ones. Or do you suggest to use the facebook logo instead of your company's logo?

Comment: @zeroflagL i understood it to be for social media icons. i would suggest Illustrator for making a company logo. Anyway it's not like i posted it as an answer it was just a suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad I was trying to bind HTML number codes, which is why this happened. Now, I've started using class names and its working.